# Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I have a task (query) running some php code that retrieves data from gmail mailboxes. It has been working fine until last friday (April 10th, 2015) and now I'm getting this error log:

```
E 11:58:26.094 2015-04-15  200   3.38 KB   14.2s /code.php
  0.1.0.2 - - [15/Apr/2015:07:58:26 -0700] "POST /code.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3462 "https://xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/start.php?email=test@email.com" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "mailroof-test.appspot.com" ms=14201 cpu_ms=407 cpm_usd=0.001221 queue_name=worker task_name=13657588804765054031 instance=00c61b117c031f6c5ded2e3d1653abac0f4b87fa app_engine_release=1.9.19
    E 11:58:26.088 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=100&labelIds=INBOX&pageToken=12866883594511227777): failed to open stream: Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile
      Fetch error'' in /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxxx/1.383623356139435513/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Stream.php:140
      Stack trace:
      #0 /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxxx/1.383623356139435513/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php(133): Google_IO_Stream->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
      #1 /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxxx/1.383623356139435513/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(61): Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
      #2 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
      #3 /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxxx/1.383623356139435513/google-api-php-client/src/Goo in /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxxx/1.383623356139435513/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Stream.php on line 140
```

This is becoming an issue since it happens once every so often.

If anyone has any idea what might be going on or how to catch the error, that will be most appreciated.

Comment: Did your certificate expire?

Comment: What version of api client lib are you using? Have you tried the latest version? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: @Bex the certificate is fine. In fact, it is working with no problems now. But every once in a while, it returns this error. And the whole task dies.

Comment: @Mars I'm going to try that since I've been using a version from January. I just downloaded the new one and I can see some changes. Perhaps it helps.

Comment: @Alberto: has upgrading solved your issue?

Comment: Actually, I added an error catcher (try... catch) and every time it catches an error, it skips that message and then re-schedules the data retrieval one more time.

Comment: @Alberto, Would you mind helping me to set up/code this error catcher? I need to upload a big file that was already working with the resumable upload but now it just stops and wont resume ( i haven't implemented any other code for the uploader, is the one from google's api example so no error catcher)

Comment: Sure, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of the API as of 25 April I think, and do this action: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719310/1834922.

I´m testing it right now as I have the same issue but for a Drive app. So far it's working but a 10 GB file takes a long time to really know. Will update.