# Resumable Upload gets interrumpted after few GB

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have a function in php to upload several files through a stand alone script, the first ones upload fine but the last one that's 16GB around 20 minutes it gets interrumpted for no reason and the upload stops. The auth is already handled, so I don't know what may be causing this issue. Here's the code and the error that it outputs:

```
function insertFile($client,$service,$filePath,$name,$fId){

    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->title = $name;       
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($fId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));

    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;


    $client->setDefer(true);
    $request = $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'uploadType'=> 'resumable'
        )
    );

    $finfo= finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);




    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
          $client,
          $request,
          finfo_file($finfo, $filePath),
          null,
          true,
          $chunkSizeBytes
    );


    $media->setFileSize(filesize($filePath));
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($filePath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }



    $result = false;
    if($status != false) {
        $result = $status;                          

    }

    fclose($handle);

    $client->setDefer(false);

}
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unape=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UoRrzX46hJ02lIDkCJi03MFbE2KVP2LDCBOgnuiclONk3sBvSctZxW3NxsWt /libs/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Stream.php
Stack trace:
#0 /libs/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Abstract
#1 /libs/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/MediaF
#2 /root/name.php(199): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk(
#3 /root/name.php(102): insertFile(Object(Google_Client), /libs/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Stream.php on l
```

Comment: PHP has a maximum allowable file upload size, check this in your `PHP.ini` file.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not uploading I think. In the ini it says 2MB limit, and yet I still can get to around 3 or 4GB. Although I'm uploading it by chunks, so maybe that could be why I'm not having an error right away.

Comment: I think then it's not the size but a time catch, either the sending or receiving server is turning off the connection after x amount of time? I'm sorry I can't say where to look for this variable, though.

Comment: I do have set_time_limit(0); for the execution time, but the cosntant in the problem is that it's around the 20 minute mark when it fails, so maybe its a set time or a set size.

Comment: as I say I'm not expert at this point, but I would suggest to check if there is a cutoff time on either the from or to servers OS cutting the transfer. Your error is actually that you have an uncaught exception - so can you hack a debug way of outputting the core exception value(s) and seeing if they shed light on it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/12/23/getting-started-with-the-cloud-datastore-on-php-app-engine/

The problem is in the Stream library, inside the IO folder. "As a temporary workaround, try commenting out the following clause from IO/Stream.php at line 107:"

```
if (!$this->client->getClassConfig("Google_Http_Request", "disable_gzip")) {

    $url = self::ZLIB . $url;

}
```

EDIT: Still didn't work, trying with the MediaFileUpload hotfix of doing the following code in lines 240~ish:

```
 private function transformToUploadUrl()
  {
    $base = 'https://www.googleapis.com';   //Hardcoded, cambiar si 
    $this->request->setBaseComponent($base . '/upload');
  }
```